# C# Speech recognition grammar

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, speech-recognition, speech, sapi

After updating my Visual Studio 2015 I have encountered a problem with previously working speech recognition.

I'm getting the following error:

```
Information: 0 : SAPI does not implement phonetic alphabet selection.
```

Actually, it happens during loading the grammar.
I tried both using code provided on MSDN forum and searching the web for a solution.

The solution concerning **Culture** didn't work for me, as well as the ["proofed" code](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn857362.aspx)...
What can the problem be?

Comment: Can you show the relevant code?

Comment: i have added the link to exect code